How to handle upgrade request by Socket.io connection to http server on nodejs. Error thrown- "Connection" header missing
I am new to websockets and socket.io I have created a web app that is running on HTTP server. I have used express.js as middleware and http module provided by node_modules. My host provider (a2hosting) has provided me SSL certificate and key thus allowing me to run my site on HTTPS. The problem is when the socket.io is requesting an upgrade the connection is rejected and an error is thrown: "Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing"
My server.js looks like this:
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const server = require('http').createServer(app)

const io = require('socket.io')(server)

const parser = require('body-parser')

const compression = require('compression')

const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')

const hbs = handlebars.create({ extname: 'hbs' })

app.use(compression())

app.use(parser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(parser.json())

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine)

app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

app.use(express.static('res'))

// some app.get() and app.post() routings goes here

io.on('connect',socket => { socket related events handlers code goes here })

// a2hosting provides dynamic ports to hosted apps so there is no port number inside app.listen()

app.listen()

My client.hbs has basic html code and the script tag to include socket.io
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

My client.js looks like
const socket = io()

socket.on('someEvent',someData=>{doSomething})

socket.on('otherEvent',otherData=>{doSomethingElse})

socket.emit('eventName',dataToBeSent)

// other JS functions

I tried adding below code, As suggested by https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_upgrade
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
  socket.write('HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n' +
               'Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n' +
               'Connection: Upgrade\r\n' +
               '\r\n')

  socket.pipe(socket); // echo back
})

Adding this code threw another error WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing
a2hosting works on phusion passenger privded by cloudlinux. I am completely lost here. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357539/sec-websocket-accept-header-is-missing-in-chrome-17

@Fox Hi, the link you provided is related to PHP and websocket and my issue is on NodeJS and socket.io update handling.

I have solved this issue for anyone who is stuck at my place.
I had added following code to my server.js
// After const app = express()

const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

And edited my "upgrade" event listener as follows:
// After const server = require('http').createServer(app)

server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {

    let key = req.header('Sec-WebSocket-Key')
    let conc = key + '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'

    let hash = crypto.createHash('sha1')

    hash.update(conc)

    let encoded_data = hash.digest('base64')

    socket.write('HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n' +
        'Upgrade: websocket\r\n' +
        'Connection: Upgrade\r\n' +
        `Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ${encoded_data}\r\n` +
        '\r\n')

    socket.pipe(socket) // echo back
})

Above code solved my initial issue.
